# UINavigation controller: present and dismiss programmatically

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I have a TableViewController which I want to present modally and I need it to have a NavigationBar.

To get that navbar, I have an embedded UINavigationController and as far as I know, that UINavigationController is what I have to present modally, so that's what I've done.

Everything works just fine, but I can't manage to dismiss that controller properly. Here is what I've got so far:

```
func presentErrorMessages(errorMessages: [String]) {
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Message", bundle: nil)

    let infoMessagesNavigationViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InfoMessagesNavigation") as! ModalNavigationController

    let infoMessagesTableViewController = infoMessagesNavigationViewController.viewControllers[0] as! InfoMessagesTableViewController
    infoMessagesTableViewController.errorMessages = errorMessages

    self.navigationController?.present(infoMessagesNavigationViewController, animated: true)
}
```

I use that to present ModalNavigationController, and this to dismiss it:

```
class ModalNavigationController: BaseNavigationController {

    var backNavItem = UINavigationItem()
    var okNavItem = UINavigationItem()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: self, action:  #selector(dismissModal))
        backNavItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton

        ...

        var items = [UINavigationItem]()
        items.append(backNavItem)

        self.navigationBar.items = items
    }

    @objc func dismissModal() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

When I press that back button, there is no change but the navbar which gets blank (with no title). I have the feeling that the application just 'forgets' what is the NavigationController used before the new one is presented.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .done, target: self, action:  #selector(dismissModal))
    ...
}

@objc func dismissModal() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by placing and invoking the `dismiss`function on my TableViewController rather than my NavigationController:

```
...
public func setBackButton(){
    if self.navigationController != nil {
        let item = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(dismissModal))
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = item
    }
}

@objc func dismissModal() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```